# How to use multiple users table in ACL plugin for CakePHP 3.2?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I have three different types of users, all stored in different tables. I want to implement ACL to allow/deny certain access to them. The default behavior of cakephp acl plugin uses the "users" table & assigns them in "groups". Is there any way i can customize this to use multiple users table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it too difficult to modify your schema to use a single table with a column storing the user type?

Comment: I guess you are using [this](https://github.com/cakephp/acl) plugin. I see that it have a configuration parameter named 'userModel' that is set to users. I think you can change that.

Comment: @arilia: I have completed almost 25% of the project. The users can login separately from their login page. If i change my schema, what all changes do i need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disclaimer: I did not test what I'm going to write

I see that Acl have a `userModel` parameter that you can config (see [here](https://github.com/cakephp/acl/blob/master/src/Auth/BaseAuthorize.php#L50)).

So when loading the component you have to set it according to you actual user table

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authorize' => [
        'Acl.Actions' => [
            'actionPath' => 'controllers', 
            'userModel' => 'Users' // <== you can change this
                                   // i.e. to Guests, Admins...
        ],
    ],
```

of course you hve to set  as requester every Table that can login

```
 $this->addBehavior('Acl.Acl', ['type' => 'requester']);
```

The only problem I see here is that you don't know what kind of user you have until he is logged in. So you can set 'userModel' only after login. Maybe this can cause some issue at the login phase, I'm not sure.

Anyway I still believe that the simpler way is to use a single table and different roles.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Though I have not implemented it yet, I hope it should work.

Comment: I have changed the userModel field but that works only for one model. Is there a way I can pass multiple userModel as an array? Moreover the ACL works only when the Auth is configured in App controller.

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to contribute but might help someone else out there. I solved this my organising my code to use prefixed routes e.g you create a prefixed route in controllers "Admins" inside admin create AppController, load your Auth component in there and specify the userModel for admins say for example Users. You could have another route "vendorsPortal" create appController inside it load your Auth Component set UserModel to as Vendors model. Hope this helps